# TextBlock с подсветкой текста

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Столкнулся с необходимостью выделения фрагмента текста в TextBlock, а именно определённых ключевых слов по которым были отфильтрованы элементы ListBox , этот текстовый блок собственно и содержащие

XAML, мой ваиант

```
<ListBox Name="ProcedureList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProceduresView.View}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <StackPanel Name="ProcedurePanel" PreviewMouseDown="ProcedurePanel_OnPreviewMouseDown">
                                    <DockPanel Width="{c:Binding ElementName=MainPanel, Path=Width-40}">
                                        <!--<TextBlock Name="MainText"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />-->
                                        <htb:HighlightTextBlock Name="MainText"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                                                <htb:HighlightRule
                                                    IgnoreCase="{Binding IgnoreCase, Source={StaticResource SourceVm}}" 
                                                    HightlightedText="{Binding Path=title, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}">
                                                    <htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                                                        <htb:HighlightBackgroung Brush="Yellow"/>
                                                    </htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                                                </htb:HighlightRule>
                                            </htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                                        </htb:HighlightTextBlock>
                                    </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>

                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Вариант XAML, рекомендованный VladD, не создаёт коллекцию HighlightRulesCollection (хотя казалось бы даже отрабатывает конвертер)

Используется компонент написанный нашим соотечественником с открытым исходным [Компонент](https://github.com/iRumba/HighlightedTextBlock)

[Описание компонента](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314060/)

Закомментированный код это старый TexBlock без выделения

Новый компонент HighlightTextBlock прекрасно выделяет текст если использовать статический ресурс, как в примере, но когда я пытаюсь его привязать к текущему тексту он не может найти это поле :( , я новенький в WPF помогите разобраться с

```
HightlightedText="{Binding Path=title, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}"
```

Изначально вопрос звучал как верно привязать это свойство к title ?
Мне дали совет по реструктуризации XAML, через ресурсы , но это не работает т.к. не создаётся HighlightRulesCollection и выделение не работает.

В ходе обсуждения было высказано предположение что следует несколько модифицировать сам компонент и поместить коллекцию HighlighRule (также) в визуальное дерево. Тогда будет автоматически наследоваться DataContext и по идее будет работать привязка через ElementName.

Подскажите как это можно реализовать? или может кто то внесёт правки в исходный код компонента ?

Альтернативный вариант , подскажите, как реализовать такого рода функционал другими методами ?

структура DataContext

```
public ObservableCollection<Procedure> Procedures { set; get; }
public CollectionViewSource ProceduresView { set; get; } = new CollectionViewSource();

    ....

    Procedures = new ObservableCollection<Procedure>();

    ProceduresView.Filter += Procedures_Filter;
    ProceduresView.Source = Procedures;

    ....

public class Procedure : ObservableObject 
{
    ....
    public String title { get; set; }
    ....
}
....

// Просто фильтрация

void Procedures_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Procedure procedure = (Procedure) e.Item;
    Boolean flag = false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        Setting.Filter sfilter = new Setting.Filter();
        sfilter.type = "искать везде";
        sfilter.text = filter;
        ObservableCollection<Setting.Filter> arr = new ObservableCollection<Setting.Filter>();
        arr.Add(sfilter);
        if (Utils.AssignedProcedureFromFilter(procedure, arr)) flag = true;
    }
    else flag = true;
    e.Accepted = flag;
}
```

[Видео с описанием проблемы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VFqRuc8CpM)

[Упрощённый проект эмитирующий мой функционал](https://github.com/leganas/TestTextBlock)

Comment: Кстати, автор репозитория [есть на ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188906/irumba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл работающее решение своей задачи

```
    public class SearchHightlightTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public SearchHightlightTextBlock() : base() { }

    public String SearchText
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SearchTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnDataChanged(DependencyObject source,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)source;

        if (tb.Text.Length == 0)
            return;

        string textUpper = tb.Text.ToUpper();
        String toFind = ((String)e.NewValue).ToUpper();
        int firstIndex = textUpper.IndexOf(toFind);
        String firstStr = "";
        String foundStr = "";
        if (firstIndex != -1)
        {
            firstStr = tb.Text.Substring(0, firstIndex);
            foundStr = tb.Text.Substring(firstIndex, toFind.Length);
        }
        String endStr = tb.Text.Substring(firstIndex + toFind.Length,
            tb.Text.Length - (firstIndex + toFind.Length));

        tb.Inlines.Clear();
        tb.FontSize = 16;
        var run = new Run();
        run.Text = firstStr;
        tb.Inlines.Add(run);
        run = new Run();
        run.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
        run.Text = foundStr;
        tb.Inlines.Add(run);
        run = new Run();
        run.Text = endStr;

        tb.Inlines.Add(run);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchText",
            typeof(String),
            typeof(SearchHightlightTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnDataChanged));
}
```

Использовать вот так

```
<parser:SearchHightlightTextBlock SearchText="{Binding Path=title, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}" Text="{Binding title}"/>
```

Не совсем элегантное решение , но работает привязка и все дела :)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы пользуетесь MVVM, то ваш `title` должен быть открытым свойством в вашей VM. То есть, в `DataContext`'е.

Если вы привязываетесь не к `DataContext`'у, то вы должны указать `Source` (если вы привязываетесь к какому-то другому объекту) или `ElementName` (если к свойству другого контрола).

---

Обновление: Ваш случай, на самом деле, более серьёзный. `DataContext` у вас, судя по всему, правильный. Но ваше Binding-выражение находится внутри сеттера свойства `HighlightRules`, которое не является частью логического дерева (т. к. не доступно как Child-элемент вашего контрола). А элементы, которые не находятся внутри логического дерева, принимают участие в привязках лишь ограничено: в них нет ни наследования `DataContext`'а, ни доступа по имени через `ElementName`. В качестве решения должна сработать привязка к элементу через `x:Reference`. В моём (сильно порезанном) тестовом примере срабатывает `HightlightedText="{Binding Path=DataContext.title, Source={x:Reference MainText}}"`.

Но, если прямо заменить на это, срабатывает странная ошибка:

> 'Не удается вызвать MarkupExtension.ProvideValue из-за циклической зависимости. Свойства внутри MarkupExtension не могут ссылаться на объекты, ссылающиеся на результат MarkupExtension.

Метод обхода ошибки нашёлся [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6858917/276994): нужно положить ваш элемент в ресурсы. Получаем вот такое:

```
<htb:HighlightTextBlock Name="MainText" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" 
                        Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <htb:HighlightTextBlock.Resources>
        <htb:HighlightRule x:Key="HR"
            IgnoreCase="{Binding IgnoreCase, Source={StaticResource SourceVm}}" 
            HightlightedText="{Binding Path=DataContext.title, Source={x:Reference MainText},
                                       Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}">
            <htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                <htb:HighlightBackgroung Brush="Yellow"/>
            </htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
        </htb:HighlightRule>
    </htb:HighlightTextBlock.Resources>
    <htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
        <local:HighlightRulesCollection>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="HR"/>
        </local:HighlightRulesCollection>
    </htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
</htb:HighlightTextBlock>
```

---

Обновление. По идее, можно решить проблему более простым образом: поместить  все `VisualRule` в логическое дерево. Это делается так: в классе `HighlightTextBlock` добавляем метод

```
protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
{
    get
    {
        var baseChildrenIter = base.LogicalChildren;
        while (baseChildrenIter.MoveNext())
            yield return baseChildrenIter.Current;
        var rules = HighlightRules;
        if (rules != null)
        {
            foreach (var rule in rules)
                yield return rule;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее, в методе `HighlightRulesChanged` класса `HighlightTextBlock` дописываем:

```
foreach (var rule in col)
{
    rule.HighlightTextChanged += tb.Rule_HighlightTextChanged;
    // добавляем это:
    tb.AddLogicalChild(rule);
}
```

А также в соседнем `HighlightRules_CollectionChanged` добавляем

```
case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
    foreach (HighlightRule rule in e.NewItems)
    {
        // добавляем это:
        AddLogicalChild(rule);
        _ruleTasks.Add(rule, new TaskQueue(1));
        SubscribeRuleNotifies(rule);
        BeginHighlight(rule);
    }
    break;
case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
    foreach (HighlightRule rule in e.OldItems)
    {
        // добавляем это:
        RemoveLogicalChild(rule);
        //rule.HightlightedText = string.Empty;
        _ruleTasks.Remove(rule);
        UnsubscribeRuleNotifies(rule);
    }
    break;
case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
    foreach (HighlightRule rule in e.OldItems)
    {
        // добавляем это:
        RemoveLogicalChild(rule);
        //rule.HightlightedText = string.Empty;
        _ruleTasks.Remove(rule);
        UnsubscribeRuleNotifies(rule);
    }
    break;
```

После этого можно будет привязываться так:

```
<htb:HighlightTextBlock x:Name="MainText" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16"
                        Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
        <htb:HighlightRulesCollection>
            <htb:HighlightRule HightlightedText="{Binding Path=title,
                                   Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}"/>
        </htb:HighlightRulesCollection>
    </htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
</htb:HighlightTextBlock>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68462/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-textblock---).

Comment: <htb:HighlightRulesCollection>
         <StaticResource ResourceKey="HR"/>
</htb:HighlightRulesCollection>  , при просмотре в Отладке , визуальное дерево HighlightRules , пустое (как будто не создалась коллекция) , у вас не будет предположений почему такое может быть ? (оригинальный вариант без ресурсов создаёт 1 элемент коллекции с пустым полем HightlightedText правда)

Comment: @AndreyLehan: Снова обновил ответ, пробуйте!

Comment: а вы пробовали у вас сработало ?

Comment: видео процесса https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FD29AKXEI48&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @VladD а почему ? local:HighlightTextBlock, я подключил его как <htb:HighlightTextBlock , и ни каких изменений собственно от оригинальной версии не произошло

Comment: @AndreyLehan: У меня работало на более ограниченном примере, я не пробовал полностью.

Comment: @AndreyLehan: `local` — это опечатка, исправил.

Comment: @VladD ну более ограниченного примера чем у меня, я придумать не могу :( просто ListBox , этот компонент и кнопка , а можете выложить свой вариант куда нибудь , пожалуйста (пока оба варианта не работают :( хотя чувствую решение где-то рядом) (кстати мой вариант выложен на GitHub , ссылка есть в шапке)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68621/discussion-between-andrey-lehan-and-vladd).